# Is there any possibilities to get coordinates of the specific area on the background image?

Tags: java, libgdx, 2d

So i am new to libgdx and i am thinking about making 2D quest. I want to know how to interact with the objects on the backround image. For example, i have this location [image: Simple room with window]

Is it possible to get the window's coordinates so that if the player is next to it (I want to check the interaction possibilities by the player's coordinates and the interactive object's coordinates), he can press "E" or do something like that?

I was thinking about putting certain images in the background, but I don't know if that's a good idea. I also saw something about TextureRegion but I don't think it can help me because I still don't know how to get the coordinates of a specific area in the background.

Comment: Unless you can write an extremely sophisticated AI that you can instruct "find coordinates of the window in this image", you're going to have to do it manually, like in an image program like Gimp. You could maybe store coordinates of hot-spots of each background in a JSON file or similar and load it at runtime to read the data. You'll have the coordinates of the item in the texture's coordinate system, but then you'll need to translate that to your game's world coordinates. That will depend on how you are managing world coordinates and sprite scales in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Colour code the objects. From the appearance of your game its retro adventure so you are using a restricted palette. A restricted palette has advantages! So if you have windows with two colours, doors with 2 different and separate colours, objects with 2 different separate colours, then you can check when the player gets near a window, or whichever, by seeing what active colours are present on a radius around the player location.
So e.g. the floor and walls are coloured of course but they never trigger anything. This does limit you to one window per room, or one type of object per room (unless you introduce a new window colour pair to distinguish them). The code would be just sample all the pixels in the area around the player maybe a rectangle would be better.